# Flutter: ListenableBuilder is rebuilding the child widget

Tags: flutter, dart, listener, flutter-change-notifier, changenotifier

The [child](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/ListenableBuilder/child.html) widget of the [ListenableBuilder](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/ListenableBuilder-class.html) is rebuilt even though it claims to preserve the child widget from re-building.

In the example below `counterNotifier` is an instance of `ChangeNotifier`. I believe there is no need to see its implementation, I'm simply calling `notifyListener()` when changes are done.

```
      ListenableBuilder(
        listenable: counterNotifier,
        builder: (context, child) {
          if (counterNotifier.isLoading) {
            return const AppLoader();
          }
          if (counterNotifier.value == null) {
            return const SizedBox.shrink();
          }
          return Row(
            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
            mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
            children: [
              child!,
              Text('${counterNotifier.value}'),
            ],
          );
        },
        child: const CountText(),
      ),
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Issue

The reason why the child is rebuilt is that I was returning the widget **conditionally** in the builder callback.

This changes the widget tree as per the condition, hence the `child` was not preserved in the widget tree.

---

### Fix

To fix this, we can use `Offstage` which hides the widget from view but the widget is still present in the widget tree.

---

### Example

After changes the `ListenableBuilder` will look like this:

```dart
return ListenableBuilder(
  listenable: listenable,
  builder: (context, child) {
    final isLoading = listenable.isLoading;
    final hasData = listenable.value != null;
    return Stack(
      children: [
        Offstage(
          offstage: !isLoading,
          child: const AppLoader(),
        ),
        Offstage( // <-- This one is unnecessary in this case. This is just for the sake of converting the code.
          offstage: !hasData,
          child: const SizedBox.shrink(),
        ),
        Offstage(
          offstage: isLoading || !hasData,
          child: Row(
            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
            mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
            children: [
              child!,
              Text('${listenable.value}'),
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ],
    );
  },
  child: child,
);
```

---

### Note

Instead of `Stack`, you can use whatever best suits you.